# I'm trying to toggle a class in reactjs but it doesn't work

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to toggle a class that would set the display value of it to none but it doesn't work, why?(I'm using react.js):

```
function sleep(milliseconds:any) {
          return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds);
          });
     }

     async function setHeight(el:any) {
          const size = el.current!.scrollHeight === 288;
          el.current!.style.setProperty("width", (size) ? "38rem" : "18rem")
          el.current!.style.setProperty("height", (size) ? "38rem" : "18rem")
          await sleep(500);
          circle.current!.classList.toggle("hidden")
     }
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
     display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use a life cycle for the component or a hook, like `useState` and `useEffect` so React knows to re-render the component.

Answer (score 0):

Had another problem myself, but then I realized that I should've written styles.hidden instead of "hidden". Still appreciate all the answers.

```
circle.current!.classList.toggle(styles.hidden)
```